# Resolving Drools rules in a different Maven package using KIE within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, drools, kie

I am revisiting Drools having not used it for a number of years.  I have two Eclipse Java / Maven projects.  Project1 contains the Drools processing logic and creates a dependency on Project2:

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
ReleaseId releaseId = kieServices.newReleaseId( "Project2", "Project2", "0.0.1" );
KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(releaseId);
```

Project2 contains the Drools rule files and is intended to be resolved using the code above in Project1.  Project1 has a Maven dependency on Project2, and the Drools/kie dependencies include:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
  <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
  <version>6.4.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

When Project1 is run from Eclipse the following error is reported:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule: Project2:Project2:0.0.1
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:117)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl.newKieContainer(KieServicesImpl.java:111)
```

Having traced the code through the execution, it looks like Aether is used to perform the resolution, however the session does not have the value of workspace reader set which (I believe) is causing resolution not to take place against the Eclipse workspace.  Any tips on how to fix this?

Comment: Your code is loading the KieModule from a Maven repository, so you don't need in the Project1's pom the dependency to Project2. Are you sure Project2:Project2:0.0.1 is resolvable from maven perspective? If not you should revise your code possibly with Example "KieContainer from KieRepository" from the Drools doc.

Comment: If _instead_ you don't want to interact dynamically with any maven repository, I suggest you follow other examples like "Default KieSession" for classpath resolution: given you mentioned Project1's pom will embed Project2 as it's enlisted as a dependency, the classpath kiecontainer loading from Project1 with resolve the KieModule in Project2 (which is in the classpath because included as a dependency)

Comment: Project2:Project2-0.0.1 is definitely resolvable from a Maven perspective - the following resolves within the Project1's pom to demonstrate this: <dependency>
   <groupId>Project2</groupId>
   <artifactId>Project2</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Are you sure? Have you tried mvn clean test from the Maven command line and from outside Eclipse?